# Twitter hashtag search results - older than 7 days

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I want to get the search results (screen_name, datetime, location, tweet_text) for Nov 12 until now for only 3 hashtags

I wrote a script in Python using tweepy, but by the time I finished the script it was Nov 20 and therefore not all tweets from Nov 12 were available (because of the 7 day window).

Tweepy doesn't work on the premium feed (30 day window) with cursors yet, so is it better to:

a) rewrite the code to use standard twitter API (this might take me some time !!) 
b) wait for tweepy to add cursor support for premium (obviously no guarantee here)
c) find someone who wouldn't mind running the 3 searches for me (assuming the result contains the fields I need)

Is there any other options that I haven't thought of ?

Comment: You could try switching from tweepy to search-tweets-Python available from Twitter, which supports premium 30-day search.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote a script in Python using tweepy, but by the time I finished
>   the script it was Nov 20 and therefore not all tweets from Nov 12 were
>   available **(because of the 7 day window)**.

this is actually one of the restrictions of using the standard twitter api. I wouldn't suggest option b, as i'm guessing you're in dire need for your tweet data asap.

you could try using Jefferson-Henrique 's solution on github. I've used his code to gather tweets from 2015 (i gathered these 2015 tweets last year). here's a [link to his github](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python). his solution doesn't use the api though. but he included some examples on how to use his script on his readme.md. i hope this helps.

/ogs

Comment: This python library supports Premium Search - [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). Here is a short example - https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/premium_search.py

Comment: @jonas i am aware of the twitterapi library sir. my answer is just a suggestion to the the asker's concern. afaik, jefferson-henrique's script (get old tweets) doesn't use the twitter api library, or tweepy for that matter. see the getJsonResponse method: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python/blob/master/got3/manager/TweetManager.py